ejabberd not using the certificates listed on config file
I installed ejabberd on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with Cyberpanel, I configured it to use the Let's Encrypt certificates from Cyberpanel, I fixed permissions and now it doesn't complain about the certificates anymore.
But it doesn't use them, if I try to access domain:5443 it gives me empty response and my browser notes it has no certificate. I can't connect any client through SSL either.
Config goes like this:
ca_file: /opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem

certfiles:
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.br/*.pem
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/conference.example.com.br/*.pem
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/upload.example.com.br/*.pem
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxy.example.com.br/*.pem
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/pubsub.example.com.br/*.pem

How do I fix that? I've been trying all sorts of things for days and it doesn't work.
ACME doesn't work either, I get an error like this:
Error: error
Error: "Challenge failed for domain conference.example.com.br: ACME server reported: 5.161.125.78: Invalid response from http://conference.example.com.br/.well-known/acme-challenge/exAmPLEcHalleNGE: 404 (error type: unauthorized)"

What am I doing wrong with this?


if I try to access domain:5443 it gives me empty response and my browser notes it has no certificate.

With the default ejabberd configuration, browsing the URL / should probably give a 404 error. Try https://domain:5443/admin/
Check also your ejabberd configuration file to determine exactly what port number it is listening, and whether TLS encryption is enabled for that port or not, and what path it is using, probably it's admin/
For example see step 2 in
WebAdmin -> Basic Setup
Also, if you get a completely empty HTML from ejabberd, maybe it crashed, and you should see some error message in the ejabberd log files.

Error: "Challenge failed for domain conference.example.com.br:

Your XMPP domain is example.com.br, that's what XMPP clients use to login to your server. And that's the domain that should be mentioned in the certificates.
If you have enabled mod_muc to use the MUC service, that one has his own domain: conference.example.com.br, and you will need it certificates too. In that case, to get certificates using ACME for that domain, you would need some ejabberd configuration that is not mentioned anywhere (or at leat I couldn't find it). Or you can try to get a certificate for *.example.com.br.
That's a topic common to all XMPP servers, see it is also mentioned in the Prosody certificates documentation:

The answer is simple - your certificate simply needs to match whatever you have in your VirtualHost and Component definitions (e.g. example.com and conference.example.com)


I found out why ACME fails, it's because certbot will only check port 80, so it was failing to do so, though I tried getting certificates using Cyberpanel options.
Apparently, Gajim was getting the proper certificate, but HTTPS didn't work when tls was set to true in configs, it didn't give any error, and said it was accepting a connection if I was using live mode to see what was going on
